# C# Windows loses reference to class library when those classes use certain objects?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, namespaces

I'm completely rephrasing (more accurately) I am experiencing with losing reference to a referenced class library from a C# Windows service.

Process:
Created a brand new C# .Net v4.0 Windows service.
In that solution I created a new class library that will be called from the service's OnStart() method, and reference is made in the Windows service to the class library.
I import the RssToolkit project (found [here](http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/)).  The RssToolkit project framework is 2.0 (doesn't matter though), but FYI.  Reference is made to the RssToolkit from the class library.

So, we have Windows service --> class library --> RssToolkit.

Windows Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using ClassLibraryToExecuteRss;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Class1.DoSomeWork();

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Class Library:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using RssToolkit.Rss;

namespace ClassLibraryToExecuteRss
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        public static void DoSomeWork()
        {
           //RssDocument rssDocument = new RssDocument();
           //rssDocument = RssDocument.Load(new System.Uri("http://www.somerssurl.com"));
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, lines of code using the RssDocument class are commented out.  With these commented out I can compile the solution just fine... but it's of little use.

Once uncommented, I receive the following compile errors in the service code:

> Error 3   The type or namespace name
>   'ClassLibraryToExecuteRss' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Projects\TestBed\TestingServiceWithXLibs\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\Service1.cs 9   7   WindowsService1

...and...

> Error 4   The name 'Class1' does not
>   exist in the current
>   context   C:\Projects\TestBed\TestingServiceWithXLibs\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\Service1.cs 22  13  WindowsService1

So what's going on here?  I built a TDD solution that works fine, but when taking the code that calls that class library from my unit tests into the solution, I get this.

I haven't changed any of the name spaces, and left everything as default.

Incidentally, I did change the target framework of the RssToolkit to 4.0... no change, and I experienced the same issue as I'm using another external library (SubSonic) in my class library.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: do you have a class named workproject in any of these projects?

Comment: No, there is no class named WorkProject - that is the project name in the namespace.  I tried adding other projects from the solution... same issue.  I was, however able to add a WCF service, make a code ref to it and compile without issue (not really what I'm looking for though)

Comment: just try with different default namespaces(Just a try)

Comment: The errors you posted are just the followup errors caused by the class library not being compiled anymore due to an error (hence the service not finding the reference anymore). Please check what errors the class library throws upon compilation.

Comment: Compiling the class library alone does not generate any errors.

Comment: Does your class library maybe autogenerate the assembly version and does the reference to the class library in your service maybe have "SpecificVersion" set to true? If so, set it to false to allow any version of your class library to be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Your server project needs to
   reference both your class library
   project and the RssToolkit assembly.
2. Make sure your service project is targeting the proper framework. Right-click on the project and choose Properties. On the Application tab, make sure you are targeting the proper framework. For instance, perhaps you are targeting the Client Profile when you actually need the whole framework.

Comment: Nope that's not it.  As per your recommendation, I added a reference to RssToolkit in my service project.  No change.

Comment: After adding the reference to RssToolkit, I, for the heck of it, added "using RssToolkit.Rss;" to the service class.  Picked up the intellisense of the RssToolkit namespace, but when I compiled, I got the same error as above, but for RssToolkit as well (The type or namespace 'RssToolkit' could not be found..."

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.  The service project was targeting the Client Profile rather than the entire framework.  So looking back at this, does the error/issue I was experiencing really make sense, with regards to the fix?  It is quite confusing as when the references are initially added, no problems until compile time.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's kind of unclear. The DLLs couldn't be referenced because "things were missing," sort of. A better error message would help.

Comment: What's the process for submitting fixes/recommendations to MS for VS?

Answer (score 2):

After further digging, [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) accurately targets this issue.  However the errors presented are really unclear, and a suggestion has been made at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com).

FROM MSDN:

> The .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is
>   a subset of the .NET Framework 4 that
>   is optimized for client applications.
>   It provides functionality for most
>   client applications, including Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF), Windows
>   Forms, Windows Communication
>   Foundation (WCF), and ClickOnce
>   features. This enables faster
>   deployment and a smaller install
>   package for applications that target
>   the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

**

> Note: If you are targeting the .NET
>   Framework 4 Client Profile, you cannot
>   reference an assembly that is not in
>   the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.
>   Instead you must target the .NET
>   Framework 4. For more information, see
>   Troubleshooting .NET Framework
>   Targeting Errors.

**

I think that the Note, however does not go far enough.  I was referencing an external assembly just fine.  The issue was that that assembly itself was referencing non-4.0 assemblies.